# How to pass values in a var into another var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have problems passing the value in a declared into another var. Not sure of the syntax.

Currently in my code below, the `<span id="xevalue1"></span>` in my html, it returns nothing, ie, blank. However if I change my script code to `$('#xevalue1').append(info.AUD)`, it does retrieves the AUD values from the json data extracted from http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD.

The following is my code. Can someone help?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

USD $1 = <span id="xelabel1"></span> $<span id="xevalue1"></span><br>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function(){
    var url0 = 'http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD';
    var cur1 = "AUD" //Australian Dollar

    window['xeCallback1'] = function(data) {
      var info = data.rates;
      $('#xelabel1').append(cur1); //label for currency
      $('#xevalue1').append(info.cur1); //extract json value from rates.AUD

    };

    $.ajax({
      url: url0,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      cache: true,
      jsonpCallback: 'xeCallback1'
    });

  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.append(info[cur1])`

Comment: Thanks. It works beautifully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Answer (score 0):

Change `$('#xevalue1').append(info.cur1);` to `$('#xevalue1').append(info[cur1]);`